# Wemo iOS SDK unable to operate Wemo Switch remotely?

Tags: ios, wifi, remote-access, upnp

I am using `Belkin WeMo iOS SDK` for **Wemo Switch** Control.I am done with the installation work and my app is operating the Switch (ON/OFF) on the same network.But when I try to change the network and operate **remotely** then it is unable to detect the available switches in the network.So I am unable to operate the switch remotely.But when I use the default wemo app by Belkin then it is working fine even on other networks.

So is there any restriction with the Belkin app for the third party to do it in a single network or there is anything wrong in my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WeMo SDK provided by Belkin is for use on local networks only. As you are experiencing, the app and switch must be connected to the same network. While it is possible for the switch to be controlled via any internet connection, that functionality requires additional authentication and is not included in the public SDK.

From the [WeMo SDK website](http://developers.belkin.com/wemo/sdk):

> The switch can be controlled through any Internet connection on your phone. But for the purposes of this SDK, they will be controlled through your local connection.